# Taking in a String, cutting the first character, then converting to int

Tags: mips

The code I'm working on takes in a string from the user in the form "X123" (not limited to 3 characters) where X can be any non-number character, and 123 can be any series of number characters. The code then strips the non-number, converts the number part to an int, adds 5, and prints the result.

```
 .data
    msgerror: .asciiz "The string does not contain valid digits."
    input: .space 9 
    open: .asciiz "Enter a string:\n"
    close: .asciiz "The value +5 is:\n"

.text
.globl main

main:

    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, open
    syscall

    li $v0, 8      
    la $a0, input        #read a string into a0
    move $t0, $a0
    syscall

    li $t3,0
    li $t4,9
    la $t0, input        #address of string
    lbu $t1, 1($t0)        #Get first digit of actual number
    li $a1, 10           #Ascii of line feed
    li $a0, 0            #accumulator

    addi $t1,$t1,-48  #Convert from ASCII to digit
    move $a2, $t1         #$a2=$t1 goto checkdigit
    jal checkdigit
    add $a0, $a0, $t1      #Accumulates
    addi $t0, $t0, 1      #Advance string pointer 
    lbu $t1, ($t0)        #Get next digit

buc1:   
    beq $t1, $a1, print #if $t1=10(linefeed) then print
    addi $t1,$t1,-48  #Convert from ASCII to digit
    move $a2, $t1         #$a2=$t1 goto checkdigit
    jal checkdigit
    mul $t2, $a0, 10  #Multiply by 10
    add $a0, $t2, $t1      #Accumulates
    addi $t0, $t0, 1      #Advance string pointer 
    lbu $t1, ($t0)        #Get next digit 
    b buc1




print:  
    add $a0, $a0, 5
    li $v0, 1         
    syscall
    b end

checkdigit:
    blt $a2, $t3, error  
    bgt $a2, $t4, error
    jr $ra




error:
    la $a0, msgerror
    li $v0, 4            #print eror
    syscall

end:    
   li $v0, 10           #end program
   syscall
```

However, my code ends up producing:

```
Enter a string:
x123
The value +5 is:
1128
```

(128 is the expected).

How can I make one of the duplicate numbers go away? I've tried incrementing the address by 1 with print statements, but it seems not to work with anything else/not as intended.

```
li $v0,4
la $a0, aString
add $a0, $a0, 1
syscall
```

The above snippet produces 23 if 123 is entered, but I can't get it to apply to the above.

Easier overall approaches are welcome too. New to mips, so I hardly think mine is all that great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you read the first digit twice.

This part:

```
li $t3,0
li $t4,9
la $t0, input          #address of string
lbu $t1, 1($t0)        #Get first digit of actual number
```

Should be changed to:

```
li $t3,0
li $t4,9
la $t0, input+1       #address of first digit in string
lbu $t1, ($t0)        #Get first digit of actual number
```